# Boethiah's Calling Sacrifice

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

At the moment all of my followers keep dying off. During Boethiah's Calling, I am at the part where I sacrifice a follower.

Since I don't want to take the time to get another follower, I was wondering if a hireling would work for this?

Being able to use a hireling would save me a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, a hireling works fine. I hired a mercenary from the bar in Riften, marched him straight out there, and sacrificed him.

Sadly, his body did not contain the 500 gold I'd hired him with!

Comment: No not that mage Marcurio! I did it to Lydia since she sucks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dark elf in the Drunken Huntsman in Whiterun.  That's who I used.